# jQuery - changing a number to words

Tags: jquery, html

I have this line of code that is outputted with the CMS I'm using:

```
<li class="productStock">In Stock: 4</li>
```

I need to write some jQuery (which I'm still learning) and I'm not quite sure how to write the formula for what i need it to do...

The number is generated by how many items are in stock, however I don't want to show the number, I just want it to say 'In stock' or 'Out of stock'. I know what I need it to do - I'm just not sure how to write it correctly.

If the number = 0 then change the number to 'out of stock'
If the number is 1 or greater then change the number to 'in stock'

If someone could point me in the right direction with this it would be greatly appreciated!

---

### EDIT

I can't seem to get any of these to work so I'm not sure if I haven't been clear enough in my explanation or I'm just doing something wrong...

Here is by issue in a little more (exact) detail:

This is the line of code:

```html
<li class="productStock">In stock: {tag_instock}</li>
```

The {tag_instock} is generated from the CMS (business catalyst) into a number. The generated number is what I want to change. So once the CMS generates the stock number, I think want to change that number into text depending if its 0 or greater than zero.

Not sure if that makes a difference or if I'm just doing something wrong with the snippets everyone has sent. :-/

Comment: which server side are you using? asp.net or php or something else

Comment: Can you try my answer and tell me what's the output or error returned?

Comment: I tried it - it doesn't change the numbers. I even tried it on its own in a blank page and couldn't get it to work. What is the 'split' function for? All I need to do is change the number. The 'In stock:' text that is currently there will be removed once I have this code working (otherwise it will say 'In stock: In stock:'

Comment: @DaveP19 I added more explanation to my answer. Also i added it in the document.ready, that should be called when page is loaded, and also your cms has updated the values. It will be useful, if there are problems, that you add some detail, if trying my answer, commenting that one.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem, starting from your html you can retrive the quantity from the string.

By doing `.split(':')` i split the `In Stock: number` string in two substring: `In Stock` and `number` and return them as an array (so i get an array ['In Stock','number'] stored as `html`).

Then i parse the number as Integer accessing it by the second item of the array (`html[1]`).

If that value is `> 0` the new html will be 'In stock', or 'Out of stock' if not.

This code is also working for multiple `li class="productStock"`, if you have,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="productStock">In Stock: 0</li>

<li class="productStock">In Stock: 4</li>

<script>
  $(".productStock").each(function() {
    let html = $(this).html(),
      items = parseInt(html.split(':')[1]);

    $(this).html(items > 0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock');
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li id ="productStock" class="productStock">In Stock: 4</li>
<script>
var numberInStock = 0 // actual number of stock 
var msg = '';
if (numberInStock > 0) {
    msg = 'In stock';
} else {
    msg = 'Out of stock';
}
$('#productStock').html(msg)
</script>
```

Comment: Remember that productStock is a class and not an id

Comment: Yep, i set the id only to get the element easier. Otherwise I can do $('.productStock')[0].html(msg)

Answer (score 0):

i think the logical way of doing this is to split the string from space

```
    var numberArray=$('#productStock').text().split(' ');
    var StockCount=numberArray[numberArray.length-1]
    if(StockCount>0)
     {
         $('#productStock').html("Stock Qty : "+StockCount);

     }
```

Comment: Remember that productStock is a class and not an id

Comment: oh apology. then in that case it will be .productStock

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="productStock">In Stock: <span class="number">1</span></li>
<script>
    var number = $(".number").text();
    
    if(number == "0"){
        $(".number").text('Out of stock')
    } else {
        $(".number").text('In stock')
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Actually I didn't get this to work.. I thought I had but it changes the number to 'In stock' no matter what it is (so even if its '0' it still says 'in stock'). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'd do.

1. Get the current number in the `<li>` by splitting it on the `:` characters (note the space after the colon).
2. Decide whether if it's in stock, or not (amount is 0 or more)
3. Replace the content of the `li` with the above result

```js
var productStockElement = $('.productStock');

function replaceStockNumberWithMessage() {
  var innerText = productStockElement.text();

  // Using 'Number()' will convert your string to a number.
  var amountInStock = Number(innerText.split(": ")[1]);

  /* The number 0 counts as false, 
     so we can use this ternary operator 
     (basically a shorter if/else) */

  return amountInStock ? 'In Stock' : 'Out of Stock';
}

productStockElement.text(replaceStockNumberWithMessage());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="productStock">In Stock: 4</li>
```